# Geolocation Permission, not on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, geolocation

Just started playing with Geolocation. And I see that you get a request (at least in Firefox) about if I want to share my location.

But then I wonder, how is Facebook able to get my location without asking the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't.

Facebook, and many other sites, use your IP address and public WHOIS data to guess where you are.

There are many databases available for this sort of lookup.  I've used [MaxMind's free database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) with decent success.

Comment: ohh i see... well maxminds is very far off when i use it.
So properbly not so good for my country (denamrk).. but thanks for the info anyways :)